# N2 CMS and MVC 3 RC causes "The current request for action 'Index' on controller...is ambiguous...'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, asp.net-mvc-3, n2, n2cms

I've used N2 CMS for a while now, I've just updated to use MVC 3 RC and I'm now recieving this error on every page:

> The current request for action 'index'
>   on controller type 'HomeController' is
>   ambiguous between the following action
>   methods: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index() on type
>   Project.Web.Controllers.N2Controller`1[[Project.Web.Models.HomePage,
>   Project.Web, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on
>   type
>   N2.Web.Mvc.ContentController`1[[Project.Web.Models.HomePage,
>   Project.Web, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Just to explain I have a HomeController, that inherits from N2Controller< HomePage >, N2Controller< T > inherits from N2.Web.Mvc.ContentController< T >.

Each controller, Home, Account etc don't have Index methods because the ContentController already has one.

This all worked absolutely fine with MVC 2, but with MVC 3 RC it's throwing this error.

Any ideas anyone? I can't find anything online...

Cheers,
Ash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like N2Controller has an `Index` method which should be set to [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) the `Index` method in ContentController.

The way an action method is resolved on a controller must have changed between MVC2 and 3 to take into account the inheritance hierarchy, causing this problem.

Comment: I was overriding the Index method, but I removed this and it worked....I didn't mention I was running this in the Azure dev fabric, Razor took an age to get working on Azure too!